# Output from a Python page call by a JQuery getJSON function

Tags: python, web.py, python-2.5

I'm working on a website that uses Python web.py.  There is a form where the user enters input and when the submit button is hit, a python page is called (matches) using the .getJSON JQuery function show below.

```
function buildMatches(input){
    $.getJSON("/matches", {e:input}, function(json){
      //Returned JSON object is worked on
   }
}
```

The "matches" python page grabs a value from a DB, runs some string reg ex and returns a JSON object.  Everything works fine, my question is how would I be able to output something from the python page "matches" to see what is exactly happening during the reg ex operations?  I've tried print "" (python 2.5), but I understand that would print to the console.  I've done some research but couldn't find anything for my situation.  I don't necessarily need to print it out to the HTML page, just any where where I can see what's going on.  Thanks in advance for any help.

I have access to the webserver (SSH, SFTP, etc.), I tried to log by importing the logging module, below is the code I used.  I could get it to log if I ran the page from the command line, but not when it is called by the JS page.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='./SomeClass.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

class SomeClass:
    logging.info('Started')
    logging.info('Another log')

    def __init__(self, obj):
        logging.info('In the init')

    def another_functio(self):
                logging.info('Logging inside the function')
```

I've tried setting the full path of the log and I still have the same problem where the log file will only be written or updated when I run this class from the console.  This doesn't work when the class is called by the webserver.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/.../.../.../example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Set output (or what you need) of the operations to a variable then pass that along with the response

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much access you have to the web server you can run your code manually so web.py uses its built-in web server.  Then print statements will end up on the console.

Otherwise, have you thought about simply writing to your own log file somewhere accessible with a browser?

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I've updated my question.  I do have access to the server.  I've been trying a few things and I can't get anything to work.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I added the same logging code to a class of mine that gets called by jQuery and it created the log file just fine.  The first thing I'd try is to specify a full path to the log file.  Maybe the relative path isn't what you think it is when it's called via the web server.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I've updated my question but I did try your advice.  I still can't get it to work.  I've been looking into using the wsgilog 0.2 logging from webpy using this page [wsgilog 0.2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wsgilog/0.2) and I've been looking for some more examples on how to implement the wsgilog logging.

Comment: Uhm, I dunno then.  For some reason either your new code changes aren't getting picked up, or its having trouble creating the new file when run via the web server.  Just brainstorming now: Maybe the web server needs to be restarted so it picks up your new changes?  What about permissions?  Does the user the web server runs as have permissions to create files in the target directory?  Anything helpful in the web server's error log?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for all the help.  After digging more into the setup of the Apache server and Python implementation I was able to find a solution to help me see what's going and debug my web app.  I saw that Apache config is setup to log errors and WSGI also blocks (pukes on) std.out.  What I was able to do is redirect the print command to the Apache error log files.

```
print >> sys.stderr, "Debugging print with variable" + variable
```

Then I check the Apache error log to start debugging the web app.  I thought I would share this in case anyone else ran into this problem as it was a pain for me.

Thanks again.